# variation in expression accounted for a SNP -- what's a usual percent?

Tags: gene-expression, gwas, snp

I am reading a GWAS paper that found a SNP associated to predisposition to colon cancer and was assessed for gene expression of the nearby gene. They found that the genotype accounted for 55% of the variation in the nearby gene expression. 55% sounds like a lot to me, what is the usual percent accounted for a significant SNP in a study like this?

- [**Dunlop MG, Dobbins SE, Farrington SM, Jones AM, Palles C, Whiffin N, Tenesa A, Spain S, Broderick P, Ooi L-Y, et al.**. 2012. Common variation near CDKN1A, POLD3 and SHROOM2 influences colorectal cancer risk. Nature genetics 44: 770–776.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ng.2293)

Answer (score 3):

eQTLs (expression quantitative trait loci) are variants that affect the expression of one or more genes.

There have been several 'genome-wide' studies of SNPs that directly affect expression. The actual effect sizes are hard to pin down in most of them, but in the supplementary data for [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/hmg/ddr328) is a list of the SNPs with the largest effects and coefficients of determination.

There are several common SNPs (cis-acting) that account for >50% of the variation in that genes expression in this (European) population cohort. That being said, that vast majority of variants account for *much* less variation in the expression, but this is to be expected.

I therefore can fully suppose that a disease-linked SNP could affect the expression of a gene to that degree, particularly if it is an oncogene or tumour suppressor.

Reference:

- [**Wood AR, Hernandez DG, Nalls MA, Yaghootkar H, Gibbs JR, Harries LW, Chong S, Moore M, Weedon MN, Guralnik JM, et al.**. 2011. Allelic heterogeneity and more detailed analyses of known loci explain additional phenotypic variation and reveal complex patterns of association. Human molecular genetics 20: 4082–92.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/hmg/ddr328)